# How to check the content of a POST method in Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

I am testing an `API` that after a trigger will make a `POST` method in the server and I want to guarantee that the request body has all the mandatory fields.

I can't find the correct solution yet that how to point to the request body.

It would be good if there is a way to check that the request is a valid Json, and then check each field of the Json(Name, Sex, etc).

Request Body:

```
{
  "requestId": "ok01",
  "parentRequestId": "some text",
  "formType": "some text",
  "sourceURL": "some text",
  "documentType": "some text",
  "documentNumber": "some text",
  "phoneType": "some text",
  "phoneArea": "some text",
  "phoneNumber": "some text",
  "name": "some text",
  "customerId": "some text",
  "email": "some text",
  "locationName": "some text",
  "currentAddress": "some text",
  "newAddress": "some text",
  "descriptions": "some text",
  "creationDate": "some text",
  "geoLocation": "some text",
  "ipsourceFibertel": "some text",
  "userId": "some text",
  "retries": "some text",
  "productList": [
    {
      "products": "some text"
    },
    {
      "products": "some text"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response body:

```
{
"OK"
}
```

```
// I tried like this, but it didnt work
pm.test("Check field 'requestId'", function () {
   pm.requestBody.have.jsonBody("requestId");
});
```

Comment: Does the API not return an Error when an important field is missing?

Comment: Yeah, the API is not on final version yet, so we are using Mocks, So if we change a field, it will always reply the same error.

Comment: What's the structure of the response body. To access the response data it would be `pm.response.json()` but without seeing the data, I wouldn't know what to tell it to look for. `ID` could be in some nested object in a nested array for all we know :)

Comment: The response body is "OK" or the code of failure. But i want to validate the Request body. to ensure that all the information was sent in the POST method.

Comment: You need to update the questions with an example request and response, images of what you're seeing in the app would help too. Don't add this stuff to the comments, edit the original question. Have you looked at any Postman documentation? https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/

Comment: Already changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your overall goal is here but if you wanted to check that the `requestId` property was used in the `Request Body`, you could do this:

```
pm.test("Check the request data", function () {
    pm.expect(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)).to.have.property('requestId');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, that's what i wanted!!! i couldn't reach this! I want to make sure the request is being made with the correct body!